# how to do mouse binding in hierarchical table

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nattable

i want to register action on Mouse down for hierarchical table, even if i register it doesn't seems to be working it always taking the SelectCellAction on mouse down. i created Hierarchical table referring Hierarchicaltreelayerexpale from  nattable examples.

the mouse binding i used

```
uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstSingleClickBinding(MouseEventMatcher.rowHeaderLeftClick(SWT.NONE),
                                                          new action(selectionLayer));
```

could any please tell me y it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HierarchicalTreeLayerExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_600_GlazedLists/_604_Tree/_6045_HierarchicalTreeLayerExample.java) you are referring to does not have a row header. Therefore a mouse binding for the row header will not have any effect.

Instead you need to use a `CellLabelMouseEventMatcher` for the `HierarchicalTreeLayer.LEVEL_HEADER_CELL` like this:

```
uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstMouseDownBinding(
        new CellLabelMouseEventMatcher(
                GridRegion.BODY, 
                MouseEventMatcher.LEFT_BUTTON, 
                HierarchicalTreeLayer.LEVEL_HEADER_CELL),
        new NoOpMouseAction());
```

Note that the selection handling is configured in the `SelectionLayer` and the `SelectCellAction` is registered on mouse down. So registering on single click will also not work, as the selection is triggered before.

Comment: @Drik thanks for the reply. If i assign my row label to the row columns and and use that to do mouse bindings. would work?

Comment: My name is Dirk! You are misspelling my name every time, which is very annoying!

Comment: And no, it would not work, as the matcher you want to use checks for regions, not for labels. If you would give more details about what you want to achieve, I could tell you what matcher to use.

Comment: i am extremely sorry sir.

Comment: actually sir, as you said the hierarchical table which i have created does not have ROW_HEADER what i want to achieve is i want to do row unselecting in single left click. i thought i would bind a my own mouse action to achieve it

Comment: Although I personally think that keeping the CTRL key pressed on click for unselect should be sufficient, I updated my answer.